# Airwatch android device enrollment

Tags: android, mdm, airwatch

I have setup the android for work account and the airwatch console too. Now when I authenticate using QR code scanner, it asks me for user name and password.
When I enter the credentials received in email, I get an error saying

`"Enrollment Blocked - You are not allowed to enroll your device. Error adding user account".`

I am using Nexus 5X, with Android 6.0.1.
Although the other device (Spice, Android 6.0.1) was enrolled, but it did not set work profile.
Also the Android for work app, is not compatible with my 6.0.1 devices.
Am I missing something? Please help me with this.

Comment: Are you a console admin? (that's AirWatch terminology) As as AirWatch admin myself I highly recommend calling support. They're excellent and it's going to be a lot faster than asking in a public space. It's REALLY hard to find AirWatch answers on Google since every environment is different and it's a proprietary product.

Comment: As Michael said, you should contact your AirWatch representative if you are in a test project, support if you are in production. Before that, read the documentation about Android for Work on my.air-watch.com

Comment: Yes I am a console admin. I am creating a test setup, to develop the app configuration flow. I have emailed support@air-watch.com 2 days ago, and I don;t have a reply yet.

Comment: I found the doc at the following link really helpful. https://resources.air-watch.com/view/fpnzykqz5pv5sk75r7kx/en

Answer (score 3):

To fix this, Go to your AWMDM Dashboard, Goto Groups & Settings> All Settings > Device & Users > Android > Android EMM Registration. Check the "**Deploy Android without registering with Google**". You are done.
[image]

Comment: I had to enable "Android Legacy" even on my Android running API Level 29 (definitely not a legacy device) to get it to work, seems there's a bug in their website.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the AirWatch Agent before you can enroll a device.